# when I insert some statement in CMD for installing and insert enter key anything happen

Tags: windows, laravel, laravel-5

I can not install Laravel on my laptop.I do the installing steps but when I insert "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog" in CMD
and press enter, anything happened.
and also Cmd after inserting "C:> Cd laravel" print this statement : "C:\Users\GREENWOOD>C:> Cd laravel
'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Let's get the important things out of the way. Laravel is first and foremost, a PHP framework. PHP, as you might be aware, is a **server-side** language. What I'm trying to say is, you should first of all have a virtual server software running on your computer.

The most common options are WAMP and XAMPP. After installing any of these software, you will want to install composer (if you haven't done that already). Next thing is to navigate to the location on your device where the virtual server's public directory is
`C:/wamp64/www/` for WAMP and `C:/xampp/htdocs/` for XAMPP. From this directory, you can happily execute your

```
composer create-project Laravel/Laravel [projectName]
```

Remember to replace **[projectName]** with the actual name of the project you wish to create.

Happy coding.